# During less than or equal to comparison what comparison is evaluated first?

Tags: c, performance

When we have simple condition (`a<=b`), what is actually happening? Will it firstly compare `a<b`, and if it's false will compare `a==b` (`a<b || a==b`)?

Comment: Please take your time to write a complete, well researched question. Otherwise it will not be useful and likely to be taken out quickly. Do not forget also to visit the site's [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: It's unspecified and depends on your compiler

Comment: It's supposed to do bitwise comparison, in the underlying registers. I'd assume it starts comparing the bits from MSB to LSB, if at any point the current bit of `b` is different than `a` either true or false is returned, else continue. If no bit difference then they're equal. So in a sense greater or less than is done earlier. All this is just an assumption though. A much more reasonable comparison is probably possible.

Comment: @El Its probably not even determined by the compiler.  Most modern instruction sets have a single Instruction for a Less-than-Or-Equal-To comparison (typically `LEQ`), which literally does the entire comparison at once, in microcode, below the level of the compiler (assuming the compiler uses the `LEQ` instruction)

Answer (score 1):

`a <= b` evaluates to true (1) if and only if `a` is less than or equal to `b`. In typical C implementations, this determination is performed via a single machine instruction. If, for some reason, multiple instructions are needed, the C standard does not specify any ordering for them, just that the result is correct.

If `a` and `b` are expressions beyond simple identifiers, the C standard does not specify any ordering for evaluation of them, their parts, or their side effects due to the `<=` operator, although there may be ordering constraints within the expressions.